# Can't access wordpress site locally after changing theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm running wordpress locally, i changed the theme using astra, starter templates and elementor, but now i can' access the site, i can access the wp-admin though ,what might be the issue

I have no clue on how to solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are some troubleshooting steps you can follow to identify and resolve the issue:

1. **Check Permalinks:** Ensure that your permalink settings are configured correctly. Go to the WordPress admin dashboard, navigate
   to "Settings" > "Permalinks," and click "Save Changes" even if you
   haven't made any changes. This will refresh the permalink structure.
2. **Check .htaccess File:** Make sure your .htaccess file is correctly configured. You can regenerate the .htaccess file by going to
   "Settings" > "Permalinks" and clicking "Save Changes."
3. **Check Theme and Plugins:** Switch to a default WordPress theme (e.g., Hello Elementor) to see if the issue persists. If the
   problem is resolved, it indicates that there might be a
   compatibility issue with the theme you were using.
4. **Check Console for Errors:** Use your browser's developer tools to check for any JavaScript or console errors. Right-click on the page,
   select "Inspect," and go to the "Console" tab. Look for red error
   messages that might indicate the source of the problem.
5. **Check PHP and WordPress Version Compatibility:** Ensure that your WordPress version is compatible with the PHP version running on your
   server. Check if there are any recommended PHP versions for your
   WordPress version, and consider updating if needed.
6. **Check File Permissions:** Ensure that file and folder permissions are set correctly. Incorrect permissions can lead to issues
   accessing files.

If none of the above steps resolve the issue, it may be helpful to provide more details about any error messages you see or any specific symptoms you observe.

Comment: This looks like it was copied from ChatGPT